# Difference between std::uninitialized_copy & std::copy?

Tags: c++, memory

What is the difference between `std::uninitialized_copy` and `std::copy` and when should I use which?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Lets say you have allocated some memory on the heap via [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) and have a pointer `T* p` to it. You end up with uninitialized storage because all `malloc` does is mark a location of the size you asked for as allocated (`new` on the other hand actually constructs objects and thus makes the allocated region initialized storage). Since the memory location starting from `p` does not have a valid object of type `T` sitting there, you cannot do this

```
T a;
*p = a;
```

since there is no object of type `T` at `p` to invoke the assignment operator on. Instead, you will have a construct an object of type `T` at location `p` using [placement `new`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new):

```
T a;
new (p) T{a};
```

[`std::uninitialized_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) simply implements the range version of the above code snippet when dealing with a range that you want to copy over to uninitialized storage.

Comment: Your answer nails it, deleted mine, +1.

Comment: Is `uninitialized_copy` exactly equivalent to `memcpy` in effect?

Comment: @MattMcNabb That would only be true if they are trivially copyable, AFAIK.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Alas, looking for more information about `memcpy` and object lifetimes turns up [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114397/constructing-a-trivially-copyable-object-with-memcpy) which you probably recognize :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, `uninitialized_copy` would additionally call the constructor of the objects created at the destination, due to the placement `new`.