# Is copying trivially copyable objects always defined in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, undefined-behavior

For a ***[trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable)*** type T consider:

```
void f(T z)
{
   T a;
   T b;
   std::memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(T));

   a = z;
   b = z;

   // ...
}
```

Is the behavior of this fragment defined in C++14 if

1. T is char,
2. T is int, or
3. T is struct { int data; }; ?

Assume that `f` gets passed an object that holds a valid value.

Do the answers change if the call to `memcpy` is replaced by *copy assignment* `b = a`?

Can the results be carried over to *copy construction* `T(a)` and *move construction/assignment*?

---

**Note**: This question, in contrast to [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175), is particularly concerned with the corner case of copying *indeterminate values*.

Comment: what is "trivially copyable" in this context?

Comment: @shafeen I'm referring to the TriviallyCopyable concept. Link added.

Comment: Following the link in the very reference you provided [Objects of trivially-copyable types are the only C++ objects that may be safely copied with std::memcpy...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)

Comment: This "question" seems to constitute several different questions. I think it would be wise to either separate them or number them explicitly. You say "for a trivially copyable type T" but then you specify possible values for T. Which is it? A general question regarding trivially copyable types, or a question regarding those specific three types?

Comment: Do we still have POD in C++14?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Comment: Warning:  Do Not depend upon the traits `std::is_trivially_copyable` or `std::is_trivial` to decide if this is safe.  These traits will not always give you the correct answer. They can answer true for non-copyable, non-movable types such as `atomic<int>`.  Instead rely on the `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible`, `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable` family of traits which inspect the triviality of each special member individually.

Comment: Also relevant [“constructing” a trivially-copyable object with memcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30114397/1708801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things at play here:

- an expression evaluating to an indeterminate value causes undefined behavior, with certain exceptions (8.5p12)
- `unsigned char` (and possibly `char`, if unsigned) is the exception
- variables with automatic storage duration and whose types have trivial default initialization initially have indeterminate values (5.3.4p17)

This means that

- `unsigned char` is fine, no matter whether using `memcpy` or `memmove` or copy-assignment or copy-constructor
- `memcpy` and `memmove` is presumably fine for all types, because the result is not "produced by an evaluation" (to meet this requirement, an implementation can use `unsigned char` internally, or take advantage of implementation-specific guarantees made for other types)
- copy-constructor and copy-assignment for other types will fail if the right-hand-side is an indeterminate value

Of course, even the valid methods for copying an indeterminate value create another indeterminate value.

---

Paragraph numbers correspond to draft n4527

Comment: I think your answer is probably completely correct, but it would be nice if you could quote relevant parts of the standard.

Comment: From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor): "Objects with trivial copy constructors can be copied by copying their object representations manually, e.g. with `std::memmove`."

Comment: @precarious: Not sure how that is relevant to indeterminate values.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not sure as well ;-). Do you have a reference that copying indeterminate values is invalid?

Comment: @precarious he's given it already - 8.5p12. (That is, when you take into account that copying by assignment uses an expression which produces the indeterminate value.)

Comment: Is copying an evaluation?

Comment: @precarious: The initializer (in copy construction), or right-hand side of a copy assignment, gets evaluated.  (The Standard talks about "the value of the expression", which is what *evaluation* retrieves)

Comment: Does this imply that copy assigning/constructing partially initialized objects is invalid? E.g. `struct A{ int i; int j; }; A a; a.i = 0; A b(a);` Doesn't this unnecessarily restrict the usefulness of POD?

Comment: @precarious: On Itanium, that goes boom.  If you use `float` or `double` instead of `int`, it can also go boom on x86.

Comment: It cannot go boom if copy construction is implemented as a `memcpy` (which does not seem to be forbidden by the standard) or am I missing the point? I'm tending to accept your answer since the standard does not explicity endorse copy assigning indeterminate values. I think that the value of an expression can be copied without evaluation as long as no calculation is involved.

Comment: @precarious No, under the standard, assignment is an evaluation.  The standard places no restrictions on the behavior of ill-formed programs.  One such behavior would be doing what *you* expect consistently and every time.  Another such behavior would be to detect that one such branch of code does this operation and logically deduce that that branch will not be followed, eliminating tests that lead to that branch during optimization.  Note that gcc can do this when your code relies on signed integer overflow "doing what you expect the hardware to do": it is UB, so they optimize it away.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for explaining the issue in detail!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's well defined for all those cases. The answers do not change if `memcpy` is replaced by copy assignment (copying for trivially copyable types *is* byte-wise copy. That's what makes it trivial), and for all trivially copyable types, move construction IS copy construction, so there's no difference there either.

From [basic.types]:

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type T, **whether or not the object
>   holds a valid value** of type T, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array
>   of char or unsigned char. If the content of the array of char or unsigned char is copied back into the
>   object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

and:

> For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where
>   neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up `obj1` are copied
>   into `obj2`, `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> T* t1p;
> T* t2p;
> // provided that t2p points to an initialized object ...
> std::memcpy(t1p, t2p, sizeof(T));
> // at this point, every subobject of trivially copyable type in *t1p contains
> // the same value as the corresponding subobject in *t2p
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

where:

> **Arithmetic types** (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types (3.9.2), std::nullptr_-
>   t, and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called scalar types. Scalar types, POD classes
>   (Clause 9), arrays of such types and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called POD
>   types. Cv-unqualified **scalar types, trivially copyable class types (Clause 9)**, arrays of such types, and nonvolatile
>   const-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called **trivially copyable types**.

Where, from [class]:

> A *trivially copyable class* is a class that:
>   (6.1) — has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
>   (6.2) — has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
>   (6.3) — has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
>   (6.4) — has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
>   (6.5) — has a trivial destructor (12.4).

So, `char`, `int`, and `struct { int data; };` are all trivially copyable types. The former two are cv-unqualified scalar types and the latter is a trivially copyable class type.

Comment: From the quote: "Provided that t2p points to an initialized object".  This condition is not met here.

Comment: @BenVoigt that doesn't mean that the `memcpy` provokes UB, though, does it?

Comment: That proves that the `memcpy` case is defined. Where is defined that *trivial copy assignment* is the same as *memcpy* (and particularly does not access the object's value)?

Comment: @precarious: I don't think this text actually proves that `memcpy` is ok.  Your second point is definitely an issue (and I believe Barry's answer has gotten it wrong)

Comment: @BenVoigt Examples are non-normative, and pretty sure that text is there to imply that the pointers are non-null. If the source type is a default-initialized trivial type, then it has some unspecified value, so copying it will also have the same unspecified value.

Comment: @Barry: The standard is pretty clear on "no initialization is performed".  I don't think it's fair to argue that creates an "initialized object".

Comment: @BenVoigt Nowhere am I requiring or arguing for the existence of an "initialized object."

Comment: @Barry copying via assignment, though, requires the use of an expression yielding the indeterminate value - and that provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @davmac: Except for "unsigned narrow character types" (`unsigned char`, possibly also `char`)

Comment: @BenVoigt right, but the question also asks about `int` and a struct type.

Comment: @BenVoigt Added another relevant quote. The exception applies here - because we're just byte-wise copying.

Comment: Can you prove the "*just*" in front of "byte-wise copying"?

Comment: I agree with Barry's latest edit, because the same paragraph that says "whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes can be copied" uses `memcpy` for its example.  However I still disagree with "The answers do not change if memcpy is replaced by copy assignment"

Comment: @Barry you may want to see my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997185/is-copying-trivially-copyable-objects-always-defined-in-c14#comment53827276_32997185)