# Is copying partially initialized structures well defined in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, c11

I recently learned that copying partially initialized structures through trivial construction or assignment is [undefined in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997185/is-copying-trivially-copyable-objects-always-defined-in-c14#comment53822348_32997822). Does the same hold true in C or does the standard guarantee that initialization and assignment behave like `memcpy`?

```
typedef struct { int i; int j; } A;

void foo() {
   A x;
   x.i = 0;
   // Leave x.j indeterminate. Is the following well defined?
   A y = x;
   y.j = y.i + 1;
}
```

Comment: There are no partially initialised `struct`s in C. (Just think about the implications for your question.) Note that `x.i = 0;` is not an initialisation, but an assignment.

Comment: @Olaf: Perhaps my wording is not correct. `x.j` is unspecified at least, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, because you do **not** initialise the struct, but assign values to single fields. But the question as such is interesting, although I would not expect much surprise here. Why not use a compound initialiser for `x`?

Comment: @Olaf I do not suggest to write such code. I'm just interested in language details and compatibilty issues with respect to C++.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you intend to write code like that in C++ you should use C. There is absolutely no use in writing code which compiles in both languages.

Comment: It's undefined in c as well.

Comment: @Olaf I do not intend to mix C and C++ but I'd like to know the differences.

Comment: @EOF Do you have a reference?

Comment: @precarious: In your particular example, `Annex J.2: Undefined behavior` of the C11 draft standard will suffice: `The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8).`

Comment: @EOF Do you mind writing an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is not "partially initialized" this is not initialized at all.
Reading `x` in your initializer for `y` propagates the "indetermined" valueness (if one can say so) to `y`. If `int` could have trap representations on your platform, this already would be an error.
But then you don't read that indeterminate field `y.j`, so there no problem at that particular assignment.

Comment: Is `A y = x;` itself an error if `x.j` contains a trap representation?

Comment: If it *is* a trap, yes. But architectures that have trap representations for integers are rare nowadays, so this is more a theoretical question. And it is theoretical, anyhow, since a good programmer always initializes their `struct` variables, don't they.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Even **if** there was a trap representation, would copying the whole `struct` it not just copy that pattern and not trap unless the copied field is accessed explicitly? IOW: does accessing a whole `struct` which contains trap representations also trap?

Comment: @Olaf, no, you could for example `memcpy` it, which is different from `=`. The thing here is that intialization and assignment are defined recursively, initializing/assigning the individual fields, and would also work for address-less objects, e.g `register`. So then the trapping field is read, and an attempt to interpret it within its type is made.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Many kinds of structures contain a number of fields which are sometimes relevant and sometimes not.  Efficiency is not improved by requiring that programs must either spend time populating meaningless fields or spend more time avoiding copying meaningless fields than would be required to blindly copy them.

Comment: @supercat, I don't understand why your are telling me this, and why here at this old question. This is just bringing the news how things are in C as it stands. In the case of this question, an initialization to `x` wouldn't do any harm. Any decent optimizing compiler can figure out the parts that are never used and optimize them out.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I was intending to respond to "a good programmer always initializes their struct variables"--I couldn't tell whether you were being sarcastic.