# Is memcpy with this pointer safe?

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy, this-pointer

I'm currently writing an own string implementation in C++. (Just for exercise).

However, I currently have this copy-constructor:

```
// "obj" has the same type of *this, it's just another string object
string_base<T>(const string_base<T> &obj)
        : len(obj.length()), cap(obj.capacity()) {
    raw_data = new T[cap];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++)
        raw_data[i] = obj.data()[i];
    raw_data[len] = 0x00;
}
```

and I wanted to increase performance a little bit. So I came on the idea using `memcpy()` to just copy `obj` into `*this`.

Just like that:

```
// "obj" has the same type of *this, it's just another string object
string_base<T>(const string_base<T> &obj) {
     memcpy(this, &obj, sizeof(string_base<T>));
}
```

Is it safe to overwrite the data of `*this` like that? Or may this produce any problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This thread makes for interesting reading; nearly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114397/constructing-a-trivially-copyable-object-with-memcpy

Comment: you can also use strcpy which stops at a NULL character. It may differ in terms of performance compared to memcpy

Comment: Another thing to consider is that modern compilers are often smart enough to recognize the loop in the first example and replace it with memcpy when appropriate. So this might be a premature optimization.

Comment: BTW, you just need to copy `len` objects, not `cap`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not safe. From cppreference.com:

> If the objects are not `TriviallyCopyable`, the behavior of `memcpy` is not specified and may be undefined.

Your class is not `TriviallyCopyable`, since its copy constructor is user-provided.

---

Moreover, your copy constructor would make only *shallow copies* (which might be fine if you wanted, e.g., copy-on-write mechanism applied with your strings).

Comment: What does "TriviallyCopyable" mean ?

Comment: I'm not sure that being trivially copyable is sufficient, although it is necessary.

Comment: @codekaizer Not at all: `std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<std::string>::value << std::endl;`. (Again, `std::string` has user-defined copy constructor.)

Comment: @DanielLangr, yeah, had just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114645/8012206). Based on the comment - *std::string is not trivially copyable in c++14 and onwards*

Comment: @codekaizer No, read the very next comment: "_An object containing a `std::string` has never been trivially copyable"_.

Answer (score 2):

It **will** produce problems. All references and pointers will be just copied, even the pointer to raw_data, which will be the same as the source object.

As a requisite in order to use memcpy, your class should:

- Be [Trivially Copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable)
- Have no references or pointers unless: static pointers or not owning the pointed data. Unless you know what you are doing such as implementing a copy-on-write mechanism or when this behaviour is otherwise intended and managed.

Comment: Pointers are fine if they do not own the data they are pointing to. Otherwise, we get multiple deletion of the same memory.

Comment: Exactly... what @Aconcagua said. Edited.

Comment: Sure, they may be reference-counted as well. As for copy-on-write mechanism. That's why I would be careful with such a strong statement.

Comment: Well I edited again but this should be it. The caution about references and pointers is mandatory

Comment: If you have reference members, and you do a `memcpy`, it means you are rebinding a reference. It's illegal.

Comment: Do you think I should put a comma? "Have no references , (or pointers unless...)" ?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, in order for `memcpy` to work correctly, the the objects being copied must be trivially copyable. For an arbitrary type like `T` in a template, you can't be sure of that. Sure, you can check for it, but it's much easier to let somebody else do the checking. Instead of writing that loop and tweaking it, use `std::copy_n`. It will use `memcpy` when that's appropriate, and element-by-element copying when it isn't. So change

```
raw_data = new T[cap];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++)
    raw_data[i] = obj.data()[i];
```

to

```
raw_data = new T[cap];
std::copy_n(obj.data(), cap, raw_data);
```

This also has the slight advantage of not evaluating `obj.data()` on every pass through the loop, which is an optimization that your compiler might or might not apply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty obvious from the limited fragment that `raw_data` is a member, and a pointer to a `new[]`'ed array of `T`. If you memcpy the object, you memcpy this pointer. You don't copy the array.

Look at your destructor. It probably calls `delete[]`, unconditionally. It has no idea how many copies exist. That means it's calling `delete[]` too often. This is fixable: you'd need something similar to `shared_ptr`. That's not at all trivial; you have to worry about thread safety of that share count. And obviously you can't just `memcpy` the object, as that would not update the share count.