# Can I implicitly create a trivially copiable type

Tags: c++, copy, c++14, language-lawyer, memcpy

My question is this:

Suppose type `T` is trivially copyable....can "create" an instance of this type without calling a constructor....like so:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>

using T = int; // T can be any trivially copyable type


T create(const T& other)
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)> my_T;

    std::memcpy(&my_T,&other,sizeof(T));

    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&my_T);
}
```

Is this defined behavior, or can I only copy into an existing object of type T?

Comment: Related [“constructing” a trivially-copyable object with memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30114397/1708801) Also related [proposal p0593 Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html)

Comment: Why do you tag C++14?

Comment: @xskxzr Because if different versions of the language had different answer, I was most concerned with the c++14 version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule, from [[intro.object]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1.sentence-2), is:

> An object is created by a definition ([basic.def]), by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union ([class.union]), or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).

None of those things is happening here, so you don't have an object. There is implicit object creation. That cast is technically UB because there is no object of type `T` at `my_T`.

What trivially copyable means is that if you then copied the bytes from `my_T` into another `T` object, then you would get the same behavior as if you'd just copied the `T` using the copy constructor. But you still need the objects to have already existed.

---

Note that this is an area that is being actively worked on, via [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html). There are many, many places where you really just need to say "I have a `T` here" and have that work, and every compiler already allows for that. It's just that that concept exists far outside of the object model that we have in C++ today.