# How to explain to the compiler that an object exists without calling its constructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to deserialize data coming from a file that is known to be in binary and valid representation of an object A followed by an object B (no padding required between them for the purpose of this question).

This is a sample to demonstrate what I mean. Feel free to mention any other problems where we hit UB, if any.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

struct B;

struct A
{
    int some_data = 0x4;
    B* ptr;
};

struct B
{
    int some_int = 0x10;
    long long some_big_int = 0x80;
};

struct ABContainer
{
    A a;
    B b;
};

array<char, 32> serialize(ABContainer* c)
{
    A* a = &c->a;
    B* b = &c->b;

    array<char, 32> r{};
    char* d = r.data();
    int* as_int = reinterpret_cast<int*>(d);
    uintptr_t* as_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t*>(d);
    int64_t* as_int64 = reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(d);

    // Stamp A values in r
    *as_int = a->some_data;
    // Store only the offset, not the full address
    as_ptr[1] = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a->ptr) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);

    // Stamp B values in r
    as_int[4] = b->some_int;
    as_int64[3] = b->some_big_int;

    return r;
}

std::tuple<A*, B*> deserialize(array<char, 32>& source)
{
    char* d = source.data();
    
    uintptr_t* as_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t*>(d);

    // Adjust ptr to point again at a valid address
    as_ptr[1] += reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(d);

    A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(d);
    B* b = reinterpret_cast<B*>(d + 16); // Hard code +16 to skip A

    return { a, b };
}

int main()
{
    // Use a container to remove stack alignment for the demo
    ABContainer c;
    c.a.ptr = &c.b;

    // serialized is the buffer that would have been filled by reading a file
    array<char, 32> serialized = serialize(&c);
    auto [a_obj, b_obj] = deserialize(serialized);
    
    cout << "a->some_data: " << a_obj->some_data << endl;
    cout << "a->ptr->some_int: " << a_obj->ptr->some_int << endl;
    cout << "a->ptr->some_big_int: " << a_obj->ptr->some_big_int << endl;
    cout << "b->some_int: " << b_obj->some_int << endl;
    cout << "b->some_big_int: " << b_obj->some_big_int << endl;
}
```

From my understanding, all dereferencing of `a_obj` and `b_obj` are invalid, as we never mentioned to the compiler that object a and b exist and are correctly initialized at these addresses.

Does `std::launder` cover this kind of use case? If so, what would be the valid code here. If not, what should I use/do to make this code C++ compliant?

Edit: Ignore padding/memory alignment requirements and assumptions (they are hard coded for the example and that's fine).

Edit2: Also ignore the serialization/deserialization design issues. If I had to implement this kind of thing for a product, I would use FlatBuffers or protobuf.

Comment: I assume we're overlooking all the various assumptions you've made about object sizes and alignments and such?

Comment: Use `placement-new` to construct objects in existing memory blocks

Comment: You can also construct trivial objects with `memcpy`. But serializing objects with internal pointers is no fun.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This has to be done before writing the bytes, otherwise the objects will be considered uninitialized.

Comment: Seems like this code would break pretty badly on any platform where `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void *)` are not both equal to 8?

Comment: I'm no expert in the wild and wonderful postmodern C++ standardese, but it seems to me that an array of `unsigned char` or `std::byte` (but **not** `char`) [implicitly creates objects](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.object-13) within itself and it's only matter of freeing them up with an appropriate cast (assuming you respect the alignment and all the rest of the requirements of course). There is no need for `operator new` or `memcpy` or anything.

Comment: However your serialization of pointers doesn't make a lot of sense. `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a->ptr) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);` What on god's green earth is it ever doing?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Just a small trick to serialize an offset from the beginning of the payload to make the example work, as serializing the full address would be nonsense when deserializing. We could also save a global offset to not have to change it when serializing and many different creative ways to manage this.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI So from the spec you mentioned, in real world the "array" would have gone through operator new[] (instead of being on the stack), which means that char* would be ok if I understand it correctly, but uchar and byte would be a safer choice to make it work no matter from where the memory as been acquired.

Comment: If you know that B follows A in memory, then `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a->ptr) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);` is a *constant* (`sizeof(A)`) so it doesn't make sense to serialize it at all (or have it in the first place). If you don't know that, then `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a->ptr) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);` is just a meaningless number that won't help you in any way. There are ways to serialize linked data structures but this ain't one.

Comment: "So from the spec you mentioned, in real world the "array" would have gone through operator new[] (instead of being on the stack)" Where are you reading this? I sure don't. "which means that char* would be ok if I understand it correctly" Again, this doesn't look like being based on what the standard says.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI We could have multiple contiguous objects each which a different offset. I do agree with this specific A/B structure there is always a 16 offset constants (with assumptions on x64, etc.)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The link you sent mentions this in section 13 "Any implicit or explicit invocation of a function named operator new or operator new[] implicitly creates objects in the returned region of storage and returns a pointer to a suitable created object." Is it because I read the sentence out of context?, but for me it seems that new[] always create objects inside the allocated array, no matter the type.

Comment: There are several separate unrelated ways to implicitly create objects. An invocation of a function named `operator new` or `operator new[]` is one of them. Just creating an array of `unsigned char` or `std::byte` by any method is another one. Calling `malloc` is yet another one and there are more. Look at `std::bit_cast` if you are stuck with plain `char` for some reason.

Comment: "We could have multiple contiguous objects each which a different offset" Then you probably want to use an offset from the beginning of the arena (C in your case) for uniformity, although it doesn't matter a lot. Anyway you should just look at boost::serialization at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::launder` requires that there already exists an object of a suitable type, which AFAIK is not the case here. We want to create a new object.

In C++23 it's pretty straightforward: just call [`std::start_lifetime_as`](http://eel.is/c++draft/obj.lifetime).

In case `std::start_lifetime_as` isn't available, there's a weird hack: you can use the placement `operator new` without the placement syntax. That is, you can write `A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(operator new(sizeof(A), d));` and that will create an object of type `A`!

This works because [[intro.object]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13.sentence-3) specifies that

> Any implicit or explicit invocation of a function named `operator new` or `operator new[]` implicitly creates objects in the returned region of storage and returns a pointer to a suitable created object.

Since `operator new(sizeof(A), d)` explicitly invokes a function named `operator new`, it is considered to implicitly create a suitable object -- even though that `operator new` simply returns its argument unchanged.

Comment: Clearer than my answer, also an alternative to pre C++23 = the entire world!

Comment: Why allocate `A` on the heap? And why do it in a such convoluted way instead of `new A`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It doesn't? `operator new(sizeof(A), d)` calls the [non-allocating form](http://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.placement) of `operator new`.

Comment: Ahh! Got it. And it's better than `new (d) std::byte[x]`, because the latter can be considered to give you a formally "uninitialized" array instead of retaining the old bytes.

Answer (score 1):

With all the comments and answers, I stumbled on this new C++23 trait [p2674r0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2674r0.pdf), which also links the relevant paper for me ([p2590r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2590r2.pdf)), which is exactly the problem I was trying to illustrate with my snippet.

The answer to this question is:

> upgrade to C++23 and use std::start_lifetime_as

As long as it's not supported or not possible to upgrade to this, any code that tries to use an object without having it properly initialized (through placement new or any other valid initialization pattern) invokes Undefined Behavior. Though it does not cause any problem in practice, per the spec and what is written in p2590r2, it's still UB.

Thank you all for your comments and help!

Answer (score 1):

In C++23, you would use [`std::start_lifetime_as()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as).

Before that, it seems you can use <s>`new (ptr) std::byte[sizeof(MyClass)]` (see it tangentally mentioned [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html))</s> `::operator new(sizeof(T), (void*)ptr)` (which is the non-allocating form; taken from [@cpplearner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76790163/2752075); [standard link](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13.sentence-3)), followed by a `reinterpret_cast`.

As for the serialization code - `+` can only move a pointer between elements of an array, and since you don't have the appropriate arrays, your use of it is technically UB (and just generally hard to read).

It's better to do pointer arithmetic on `char *` (or `std::byte *`, etc). The standard is a bit vague on those, but the consensus seems to be that those always work, even when not pointing to an actual `char[N]`.

And to **copy** to/from raw storage, use `std::memcpy`.

After all those changes, I'd do it like this:

```
void serialize(const ABContainer &c, char *target)
{
    std::memcpy(target, &c, sizeof(ABContainer));
    
    // Patch the pointer.
    std::ptrdiff_t new_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(c.a.ptr) - reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&c.a);
    std::memcpy(target + offsetof(ABContainer, a.ptr), &new_ptr, sizeof new_ptr);
}

ABContainer &deserialize_ref(char *source)
{
    // Patch the pointer.
    std::ptrdiff_t diff;
    std::memcpy(&diff, source + offsetof(ABContainer, a.ptr), sizeof diff);
    void *new_ptr = source + diff;
    std::memcpy(source + offsetof(ABContainer, a.ptr), &new_ptr, sizeof new_ptr);
    
    return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<ABContainer *>(::operator new(sizeof(ABContainer), (void *)source)));
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that `std::launder` can begin lifetimes implicitly like you're trying to. [ptr.launder p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#2) makes it a precondition for a type similar to `ABContainer` to be stored at `source`. However, you have just begun the lifetime of `std::byte[]` at the location, making it visible to the compiler that an `ABContainer` cannot exist at `source`.

Comment: Fwiw this should work if you get rid of `new(source) std::byte[]`. Without that, `std::launder` should do its job of acting as a provenance fence, and let you create a reference to the `ABContainer` stored at `source`.

Comment: @JanSchultke *"should work if you get rid of new"* But you (correctly) said that `launder` by itself can't begin object lifetime. `new std::byte[]`, on the other hand, starts lifetime of any implicit-lifetime type. It's not entirely obvious that the resulting object is not uninitialized, but my link seems to say so.

Comment: Your link explains that you must copy back into the source from the bytes created with placement-new. Also, these bytes must be elsewhere, not in the same place as `source`. You are missing this crucial step. It would be valid because `std::memcpy` can implicitly begin lifetimes. Without that step, you just have UB.

Comment: @JanSchultke Huh? I'm referring to this part: *"A new barrier operation (distinct from std::launder, which does not create objects) could be introduced to the standard library, with semantics equivalent to a memmove with the same source and destination storage. Prior versions of this document suggested [std::bless] However, LEWG review observed that `new (start) std::byte[length]` can be used to obtain the desired effect"* What is `bless` if not the same thing as `start_lifetime_as` under a different name?

Comment: I'm not taking about `std::bless` or `std::start_lifetime_as`, I'm talking about your misinterpretation of how `new std::byte[]` can be used similarly. In the proposal you've linked, [§ 3.8 Direct object creation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#direct-object-creation) explains exactly how it can be done without `std::start_lifetime_as`, and what you're doing doesn't match that. Fwiw, I also think that `std::launder` is unnecessary and may even introduce UB that wasn't there before, but that's another can of worms.

Comment: This may be fine be fine under http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13, tbf. Afaik `new std::byte[]` doesn't preserve the object representation though, which may be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, actually the problem is that `new std::byte[]` would be turning the memory at `source` indeterminate, which makes the returned `ABContainer&` unusable, although the code within this function isn't UB.

Comment: See [Implementation of std::start_lifetime_as()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76445860/5740428)

Comment: @JanSchultke *"new std::byte[] doesn't preserve the object representation though"* Yep, I'm starting to believe that. In any case, cpplearner's idea with calling the non-allocating `operator new` looks more promising, so I've changed the answer to use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Remy said, placement-new is the C++ idiomatic way to represent the fact that you're "building" (or more accurately, "placing") an (unitialized, in your case) object instance on top of existing memory. However that might not help as much as you'd think, because you have very little control over any alignment padding or control structures the compiler is free to add to your memory, thus offsetting the fields from where you think they should be.

You are absolutely barking up the wrong tree here, however. You cannot do any kind of sane serialization and deserialization like this due to a whole slew of issues:

1. Endianness. When serializing you need to set a specific endianness, and when deserializing you need to convert the set endianness to your system's to be able to use the values you previously serialized.
2. Memory alignment limitations due to the OS you're using. You are making an incredible amount of assumptions about the memory layout of your data that might not even be true for a round-trip on your specific system, let alone any kind of inter-system round-trips.
3. Perhaps less important, but your entire process is very manual and error-prone. It is also independently defined for the serialization and deserialization halves, introducing even more manual editing points of failure.

For the reasons above, you really should use a more standard approach, like `protobuf` or `json` output or the `boost` libraries, or really anything other than what you're doing here.

Comment: Though they are good advices in general for software development, this does not answer the question at all. I understand where you are coming from and clarify the question to that we can assume that I know what I'm doing here and asking for the specifics of C++ standard and rules, not to actually put this snippet in production in any way.

Comment: It does answer your question though, you're looking for `placement-new`. I'm just saying, you might not like where it takes you if you go down that route.

Comment: It does not, placement new will initialize a new object and will call its constructor, while I already have an array with the object correctly initialized, the compiler is just not aware of it.

Comment: Placement new is not the only way to create objects in a given region of storage. Endianness is irrelevant unless you are looking for a portable serialization format.

Comment: I disagree, placement new is the *only* way to create objects in a given region of space. The "alternative" you're thinking of, reinterpret cast, doesn't create anything, it reinterprets the memory as something else. Also serialization should generally be portable, though of course you're free to ignore that in your own code if you so wish.

Comment: @Sproulx, if there's no constructor to call, for example with POCO types, there will be no initialization. Is this the reason for your resistance? These kinds of bits of knowledge can be easily gleamed from just reading the documentation.

Comment: "placement new is the only way" It used to be the case when dinosaurs roamed the Earth (IOW before C++20). Not anymore, thanks to [P0593](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Exactly what I found through cppreference and type traits for C++23, which is reflected in my answer. So happy to see that my problem has been solved already and only need to wait 10 years for compiler to catch up! (joke.. kind of..) :)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that's a bit unfair, that proposal is pretty recent (<3 years) and not even supported (as far as I can tell) by all major compilers. That said, it'll be an interesting read, I hadn't seen this before!

Comment: @Sproulx note that in the proposal referenced above, the suggested operation for what you want is [an internal optimization of placement-new](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#when-to-create-objects) (at the end of the section). Your answer remains the same.

Comment: It is a part of C++20 and it just codifies existing practice. Basically, don't be evil and don't intentionally break existing C-style code with super aggressive optimisations, that's all that is needed to support it.