# Using linked functions as output on uninitialized memory?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

Suppose I have two input arrays.

```
std::vector<double> const Matrix = {...};  // 9 elements
std::vector<double> const Vector = {...};  // 3 elements
```

And one output array is uninitialized for some reason (e.g., performance).

```
double* Result = std::allocator<double>{}.allocate(3);
```

And I apply a linked C function, such as GEMV (matrix vector multiplication from BLAS)

```
dgemv(3, 3, (void const*)Matrix.data(), (void const*)Vector.data(), (void*)result)
```

I know that `result` will have the GEMV result, but does C++ as well? Legally speaking?

**Do I have to bless the memory to tell C++ that the `result` array has initialized elements?**

What about if I use `std::complex<double>`? (which doesn't have a trivial constructor, BTW)

```
zgemv(3, 3, (void const*)Matrix.data(), (void const*)Vector.data(), (void*)result)
```

**Do I have to tell somehow (before or after) calling `gemv` that C++ should regard this memory as initialized even though it wasn't C++ who initialized it?**

I know in practice it might work, but I am asking if there is something I have to do to make it standard-compliant, even if the extra step is a no-op.

---

NOTE ADDED:

This is how the code looks like and how the suggestion from @user17732522 plays out.
The code looks messy because some features are not implemented in current GCC or clang

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>

void dgemv(int n, int, double const*, double const*, double* result);
// possible implementation for all we know, it is really a linked function, maybe written in fortran, one thing is for sure, it doesn't call placement new
// {
//     for(int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
//         result[i] = 1.2;
//     }
// }

// start_lifetime_as is not implemented in gcc 13.2 c++23 so I am using this c++20, supposedly equivalente
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76794371/225186
template<class T>
requires (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>) 
// && std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<T>)  // not implemented yet in gcc 13.2 c++23
T* x_start_lifetime_as(void* p) noexcept
{
    return std::launder(static_cast<T*>(std::memmove(p, p, sizeof(T))));
}

int main() {

    std::vector<double> const Matrix = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0};
    std::vector<double> const Vector = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

    double* Result = std::allocator<double>{}.allocate(3);

    // start_lifetime_as_array<double>(std::addressof(*result), count); since this is always called on contiguos iterators
    for(int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
        x_start_lifetime_as<double>(std::addressof(Result[i]));
    }

    dgemv(3, 3, Matrix.data(), Vector.data(), Result);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5cY9sYbfh

Comment: This is fine, regardless of what the standard has to say. If the function body isn't visible at compile-time, the compiler has to assume it performs all the necessary blessing.

Comment: technically this it is UB before C++ 20 because the lifetime of the objects has not started.  I can't think of a platform where this would break though since you are dealing with trivial types.  Even `std::complex<double>` is mandate to be binary compatible with `double[2]` for C interoperability.

Comment: @NathanOliver, can I make it not UB in the cases where it is UB? (before C++20 or after)? I don't mind adding code "just in case" or exorcising UB demons since it might even clarify the code. Does `std::launder` help here?

Comment: I think HolyBlackCat has a point. If the function body is not visible, the compiler cannot assume whatever extra measure you assume you need to take to make it well-defined has not already been done in the function body.

Comment: The more I look at it this should be fine as long as the types are trivially default constructible.  Otherwise each element of the array needs to be initialized with a call to placement new.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, that is part of the equation, being agent written in another language, I know that it couldn’t have call, for example, placement new.

Comment: @NathanOliver that is what makes the case of std::complex interesting. for whatever misguided reason std::complex doesn’t have a trivial default constructor. And of course I am refusing to call the default constructor for every element just to be overwritten in the next step (see my comment in the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard generally doesn't specify the behavior of functions written in C, how exactly the C++ object model would map to the C one, or how the boundary between the two languages behaves, except for some compatibility recommendations.

So from that point-of-view the question is outside the scope of the standard.

If we instead assume that `dgemv` was written as a C++ function and that function simply writes to some `Result[i]`, then technically the program would have undefined behavior.

`std::allocator<double>::allocate` is specified to start the lifetime of the array object into which the returned pointer points, but it isn't specified to start the lifetime of the array elements. It is also not specified to implicitly create any further objects.

As a result no `double` object at `Result[i]` is alive when the function tries to write to it and outside the lifetime of the object it can't hold a value. An assignment expression also (with one specific exception for trivial union members) can't start the lifetime of an object.

In order to create the `double` objects you need to create each of them with a placement-new, `std::construct_at` or `std::allocator<double>::construct`.

In case of a placement-new you can write it without initializer, so that it won't actually write to the `double`. The other two variants will always initialize with a value, in particular they would value-initialize to zero if no argument is given.

This issue is specific to `std::allocator::allocate`, at least in the case of `double` arrays. If you used `std::malloc` or `operator new[]` instead, then the lifetime of the `double` elements would be implicitly started (because they are implicit-lifetime types and these functions are specified to implicitly create and start the lifetime of objects).

I am not entirely sure whether it was guaranteed before C++23 that `std::complex<double>` is an implicit-lifetime type. If it wasn't then it would require the placement-news even if these other allocation functions are used. However, I think that even before C++23 explicitly stating the the type shall be trivially-copyable, the layout requirements and implicit declaration of the copy constructor and destructor already effectively forced it to be implicit-lifetime.

In C++23 there is a simple library function to start the lifetime of the array objects, assuming the element type is an implicit-lifetime type:

```
std::start_lifetime_as_array<T>(Result, /*size of array*/)
```

where `T` is the array element type.

The result of this function is a pointer to the new array elements and can be passed directly to the library function which will assign to the elements. This function will complain if `T` isn't actually implicit-lifetime.

As an alternative it would work to placement-new a `std::byte` or `unsigned char` array at `Result` before the function call, then passing the original pointer, potentially after `std::launder`, to the function. Starting the lifetime of this new array implicitly creates objects nested inside it and starts their lifetime. This does not check that the type is implicit-lifetime as necessary to actually create the elements of the original object. I would recommend checking this manually, but unfortunately the type trait `std::is_implicit_lifetime` only exists since C++23 as well.

Comment: I think we are all in the same page here. What if I accept all this but also exploit the compatibility of std::complex with double[2] and do double placement new on both the real and imaginary part, in a loop for all elements? this could would compile to nothing and still please the language as for the initialization of the complex elements.

Comment: @alfC After looking at the standard again, I think I was mistaken about `std::complex<double>` not being guaranteed to be implicit-lifetime before C++23. In any case, placement-new on just `double`s when you allocated an array of `std::complex<double>` with `std::allocate::allocate` won't do. It won't start the lifetime of the `std::complex<double>` object itself, so the newly-created `double` objects can't become subobjects (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-2.1), causing the lifetime of the enclosing array object to end because of storage reuse.

Comment: @alfC If you insist on using `std::allocator::allocate` and assuming `std::complex<double>` is indeed implicit-lifetime, then you could placement-new a `std::byte` array into the storage returned by `std::allocator::allocate`. Starting the lifetime of that array causes implicit creation of objects nested in the array. Then the original pointer can access the `std::complex<double>` objects in their lifetime, but uninitialized, after a `std::launder` if "_after the lifetime of an object has ended_" in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-8 is to be taken strictly.

Comment: If `std::complex<double>` is not implicit-lifetime, then it is impossible to start its lifetime while leaving it uninitialized.

Comment: I am doing this for a container (that I can control), but I don't control (and don't want to) the allocator, so I am using here `std::allocator` to reflect that. I don't have a problem getting the allocated memory for complex, placenew byes and launder if it does something in the right direction. I don't mind doing anything that in practice and normal conditions (e.g. -O1) doesn't generate code. What would that look like? Also, I guess I have to do this before calling `gemm`, right?

Comment: @alfC If you want to the container to properly support the standard Allocator interface, you must use `std::allocator_traits::construct` on each element, because it may have custom behavior (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/construct). The interface doesn't permit default-initialization. There is however precedence of partial allocator support in `std::basic_string` which does not use `construct`.

Comment: With the allocator interface it would be up to the user to provide a type that value-initializes so that elements aren't initialized. (However this would cause UB if the container also requires the ability to copy/move the elements.)

Comment: @alfC My suggestion above was to write `new(static_cast<void*>(Result)) std::byte[/*allocated size*/];`, before the call to the function, then pass `std::launder(Result)` to the function. This will _only_ work if the element type and all of its subobjects are implicit-lifetime. I am not entirely sure whether this is true for `std::complex<double>`.

Comment: (Anyway, I doubt that any of this has any relevance in practice and the object model in the standard also clearly has some defects that might make it questionable whether one should try to match it so specifically. Also, GCC had (has?) some bugs in relation to uses of `std::launder` which I think were similar to this.)

Comment: Maybe a potential case where the original code could cause trouble in practice: Assume the allocator keeps a list of freed memory blocks and then hands them back on a new allocation, potentially for an allocator for a different value type. In that case, without properly constructing the `double` elements if LTO is used (including the library functions), the compiler might make the unintended assumption that the memory which was written to earlier as a different type cannot be aliased by `double` and may therefore optimize away access in the library function.

Comment: @alfC I forgot: In C++23 you have of course `std::start_lifetime_as_array(Result, /* array size*/)`, which is a nicer form of my suggested placement-new and `std::launder` combination (the return value can be used as pointer directly). It also has an implicit check that the type is implicit-lifetime.

Comment: and, `std::complex<double>` is precisely the example used ! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as

Comment: This is very confusing, in cppreference  it says `auto d = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<float>*>(network_data));` might old indeterminate data (which is the point here). While `std::start_lifetime_as<std::complex<float>>(network_data);` doesn't say, which makes me assume that it calls the trivial constructor, which is what I am trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: @alfC Right, what `std::start_lifetime_as` also allows you to do is pass a normal `double` array to the library function and then later, as a noop, turn the array into an array of `std::complex<double>`. This isn't possible with the placement-new approach (which technically resets all values to be indeterminate). This effect of `std::start_lifetime_as` can be replicated by a sequence of `memcpy` to an intermediate array and back, but that would have to rely on the optimizer recognizing it as not modifying the storage.

Comment: @alfC The value is indeterminate, because the implicit object creation that this relies on would initialize the implicitly-created objects to indeterminate values. That the byte array is initialized with the given bytes doesn't matter. You have the same problem when using placement-new. `std::start_lifetime_as` is special in that it is specified to preserve the object representation and give the new object the value that it would have according to that object representation. Technically this is equivalent to a memcpy into an intermediate buffer and back, but with an optimization guarantee.

Comment: This how this might look like in "real code": https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/launder/include/multi/adaptors/blas/gemv.hpp?ref_type=heads#L112-121 . For context, this odd specialization of  uninitialized_copy, calls an specialization of copy and copy_n, which at the end calls the appropriate version of gemv. What I am unsure now if I can ignore the pointer returned by `start_lifetime_as` or I have to use that one in some way.

Comment: @alfC Using the old pointer with `std::launder` should also be fine. But I am not sure whether your types are now correct. Again under the assumption that the `gemv` function is implemented in C++ and only assigns to `double`s, then `It1DOut::value_type` being `double` would be fine. If it is `std::complex<double>` then it is also fine because of the special `reinterpret_cast` guarantees (at least if you don't take them to strictly, since technically you are not writing the required `reinterpret_cast` directly). But if it is any other type it won't be correct.

Comment: gemv could be implemented in a non descript language, (ehem, Fortran, C or some vendor specific code generator) to which we can only see the assembly code. The function could take arguments by void* for all that matter. The type information is in the function name, dgemv for double, zgemm for complex (double*2). There is an implicit assumption that gemv functions only operates on float, double, complex float and complex double. what complicate things a bit is that std::complex is not trivial also if one wants to use std::complex really.

Comment: I added a note to the OP; I am also happy to say that with `-O1`, there is no extra code generated (with `-O0` there is). https://godbolt.org/z/dsa4Mxeqz