# How data in a boost::aligned_storage object is copied?

Tags: c++, boost, memcpy

The [`boost::aligned_storage`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/aligned_storage.html) data type is useful to me in order to provide aligned storage in a pre-c++11 world. I have a class that contains this storage member:

```
template <size_t StoreSize>
class RoutineStorage {
   enum { ROUTINE_STORAGE_SIZE = StoreSize};
   enum { BUFFER_ALIGNMENT_VALUE = 8 };

   template <typename TStorageType> TStorageType& getStorageAsType()
   {
       BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(boost::has_trivial_assign<TStorageType>::value &&
         boost::has_trivial_copy<TStorageType>::value,
         "The storage type must be trvially copyable and assignable to support this classes "
          "copy|assign semantics.");
        ... // Checking and some other code.
        return new (_store.address()) TStorageType();
   }

private:
    typedef boost::aligned_storage<ROUTINE_STORAGE_SIZE, BUFFER_ALIGNMENT_VALUE> 
        StorageBuffer;

    StorageBuffer _store;
}
```

I would like to provide a copy constructor for this class, but when i look at the implementation of `aligned_storage` it has a copy constructor listed as private and a comment `// noncopyable`. There doesn't seem to be an explanation for this in any of the boost pages about this type, so i concluded that they didn't want to handle copying of different possible templated buffer sizes. I suspect that the following will be fine for copying this buffer:

```
RoutineStorage(const RoutineStorage<StoreSize>& copy)
{
    std::memcpy(_store.address(), copy._store.address(), _store.size())
}
```

Will there be a problem with this? As far as i can tell the `aligned_buffer` `address` function will give the start of a continues memory address and `size` will let me always copy the correct size.

Comment: I take it somewhere in your class you have `Foo* = new(_store) Foo();`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, but the class does not internally use this. It is provided out to a user. I guess i should enforce that the type `Foo` should be trivially copy able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying the buffer like you do in

```
RoutineStorage(const RoutineStorage<StoreSize>& copy)
{
    std::memcpy(_store.address(), copy._store.address(), _store.size())
}
```

is not enough.  Yes, you will have an exact copy, but you don't actually have the object you created in that `StorageBuffer`.  [[intro.object]\1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#1) states that

> The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. An object is created by a definition ([basic.def]), by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union ([class.union]), or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).

so until you copy the object into `store` with placement new you don't actually have an object, just storage.

Lets say you are storing a `Foo`.  Originally you would create the `Foo` in the `StorageBuffer` like

```
Foo* f = new(_store.address()) Foo();
```

So, in the copy constructor you just need to call the copy constructor of `Foo` and placing that into `_store` like

```
RoutineStorage(const RoutineStorage<StoreSize>& copy)
{
    f = new(_store.address()) Foo(copy.*f);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the class does not know the object that will be stored in its buffer when it is being copied. The user of the class gets the type they require from the buffer. If i static assert that the object is trivial as in the edit to the question, is this enough?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox It is not.  I'm looking up the relevant standard section right now to show you just having a buffer is not the same as having an object.

Comment: Ok, there is a question on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114397/constructing-a-trivially-copyable-object-with-memcpy

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Awesome find.  I've also updated the answer with the relevant standardess

Comment: Hnnnn, this implies the opposite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171827/is-memcpy-of-a-trivially-copyable-type-construction-or-assignment  How is this so hard ...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Not really.  What they are missing there is everything they quote says `object`.  You don't actually have an object though until you follow what  [intro.object]/1 says